# Not able to find control in FormView

Tags: asp.net, events, formview

I am working on Asp .NET Form View . But on its FormView2_ItemUpdated event . I am not able to Find Control ..

This is my FormView

```
 <asp:FormView ID="FormView2" runat="server" DataKeyNames="ID"
                DataSourceID="SqlDataSource4" OnItemUpdated="FormView2_ItemUpdated">
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    Update
                    <table class="style17">
                        <tr>
                            <td class="style20">ID:</td>
                            <td>
                                <asp:Label ID="IDLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ID") %>' />
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <table>
               </EditItemTemplate>
            </asp:FormView>
```

this is the event

```
 protected void FormView2_ItemUpdated(object sender, FormViewUpdatedEventArgs e)
    {
        Label lbl = FormView2.Row.FindControl("IDLabel") as Label;

    }
```

I got one post that said you have to bind data first ,  also did that , but this is not solving any issue , 
I am seeing post on DataBound and ItemCreated event , but not on ItemUpdated

Is it any different code required for ItemUpdated  event ?
Need some suggestion

Comment: Provide the `DataKeyNames` of the `FormView` and use `e.Keys["ID"]` to get the ID in the `ItemUpdated` event. I think that you can't use `FindControl` because the current `FormViewMode` is not `Edit`. You can check it with: `if (FormView2.CurrentMode == FormViewMode.Edit){ Label lbl = (Label)FormView2.Row.FindControl("IDLabel") }`

Comment: I put up this code  ................
    {        if (FormView2.CurrentMode == FormViewMode.Edit)
        {  Label lbl = FormView2.Row.FindControl("IDLabel") as Label;   }.......on run time CurrentMode  is readonly ,  How can I do it on edit mode

Comment: You can use `ChangeMode` to change it to edit-mode. But i'm not sure if that is what you really want. Why do you need to find the label at all? You can get the ID via `e.Keys["ID"]` if you assign the `DataKeyNames = "ID"`

Comment: yes i should not have put lblID , But I have many controls ....even for textboxes like ... TextBox txt = (FormView2.Row.FindControl("PasswordTextBox0") as TextBox).... it is also showing same error

Comment: I try to change  to edit mode by FormView2.ChangeMode(FormViewMode.Edit); but this is also not making any sense

Answer (score 0):

The problem with trying to find a control in the FormView deals with the mode you are in vs the mode you are trying to go to. I had this problem, on a web page, where I am using Labels in the ItemTemplate and using TextBoxes (or in my specific case a RangeValidator) in both the EditItemTemplate and the InsertItemTemplate. When I tried to find any element (i.e., TextBox, RangeValidator, anything) that wasn't also in the ItemTemplate, it couldn't be found. If what I was looking for existed in the ItemTemplate (i.e., DropDownList) that also existed in the other templates then it could be found; but there is the chance the it's the wrong version of the element. I was finally able to find the element using **OnPreRender="FormView1_PreRender"**

In Debug mode (using Breaks) you will see the life cycle goes: Page_Load, FormView1_ModeChanged, FormView1_PreRender. It's the FormView1_PreRender that you want to use because it isn't until this point that the Edit or Insert controls exist. The fact that there was a problem wasn't even evident while running the page because the page didn't actually do anything when I hit the Edit button; it would just sit there. I removed the RangeValidator and the page started to work. Putting the RangeValidator back in caused the edit button to stop working.

Bottom line, if you have to access a control in either the EditItemTemplate or the InsertItemTemplate on a web page (not sure what the issue might be in a Windows app), use OnPreRender and then user FormView1.FindControl. Make sure you check to make sure it isn't null; that can still happen.